# How to resolve 'Remove from your finder: :includes => [:company]'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to write nested relation, I got bellow warning and can't get company data.

> Unused Eager Loading detected
>     User => [:company]
>     Remove from your finder: :includes => [:company]

I write bellow code.
When I check about sql. it looks like to make relation with user and company.
But this controller result can't get company data.
Do you know how to resolve this issue?

**controller/product.rb**

```
def products
  Product
    .sale_date_between(params[:from], params[:to])
    .organization(current_user.company_id)
    .order('sale_date DESC')
end
```

**models/product.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
scope :with_user, -> { includes(:user, {user: :company}) }
scope :sale_date_between, ->(from, to) { where('sale_date_date >= ?', from).where('sale_date_date <= ?', to) }
scope :company, ->(id) { with_user.where(users: { company_id: id }) }
```

**models/user.rb**

```
has_many :products
```

**models/company.rb**

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'company_id'
```

Comment: Are `organization` and `scope :company` supposed to be the same? (you haven't included a scope for `organization` but I would guess based on it passing in a company id and the `company` scope taking a company id and tacking it onto the query, I'd say they were the same)

Comment: Is this something to do with this `scope :with_user, -> { includes(:user, {user: :company}) }`? Try changing it to `scope :with_user, -> { includes(user: :company) }`